# $T:V\rightarrow W$ such that $N(T)=V'\subset V$ and $R(T)=W'\subset W$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

How should one prove that there exists a linear map $T:V\rightarrow W$ such that $N(T)=V'\subset V$ and $R(T)=W'\subset W$ if $\dim(V')+\dim(W')=\dim(V)$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces?

My "answer" is just a guess really... It seems pocketed with holes. What do you think?

Comment: I'm writing my ideas out now for this. They seem unnecessarily long-winded though.

Comment: This is the so called *dimension theorem* and it holds for all linear maps $T$.

Comment: I see now, so then how would a student prove the existence of such a $T$?

Comment: What Berci is saying is that this holds *for all* linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces, so if you write down any linear map between two finite dimensional vector spaces, it will satisfy your desired property.  The idea is that the more vectors in $V$ that $T$ sends to $0$, the less vectors it can send to something nonzero, and vice versa.

Comment: @Berci See my answer.

Comment: @Brian See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a basis $(b_1,..,b_k)$ for $V'$ and extend this arbitrarily to a basis of $V$, say $(b_1,..,b_k,c_1,..,c_s)$ (assumed that $\dim V'=k$ and $\dim V=k+s$).

1. Check that $Tc_1,..,Tc_s$ are linearly independent,
2. and they span the whole $W'=\{w\,\mid\, w=Tv$ for some $v\in V\}$.

Now, if you want a concrete example, just consider any matrix $A$ and the mapping $v\mapsto A\,v$.

Comment: Ah! Damn! You are doing what I'm doing! I don't want to look! I'll look at it after I write mine down and publish it here.

Comment: Or "post" I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my reasoning:

---

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$. Let $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_l\}$ be a basis for $V'\subset V$, let $B=\{a_1,\dots,a_l,b_1,\dots,b_m\}$ be a basis for $V$, let $C=\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ be a basis for $W'\subset W$, and let $D=\{c_1,\dots,c_n,d_1,\dots,d_p\}$ be a basis for $W$. Thus $N(T)=V'$ and $R(T)=W'$ means that

\begin{eqnarray}
T(a_1)&=&0+\cdots +0\\
T(a_2)&=&0+\cdots +0\\
\vdots\\
T(a_l)&=&0+\cdots +0\\
T(b_1)&=&k_{11}c_1+k_{21}c_2+\cdots+k_{n1}c_n\\
T(b_2)&=&k_{12}c_1+k_{22}c_2+\cdots+k_{n2}c_n\\
\vdots\\
T(b_n)&=&k_{n1}c_1+k_{n1}c_2+\cdots+k_{nm}c_n,
\end{eqnarray}

or simply

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0&\cdots&0&k_{11}&\cdots&k_{n1}\\
\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0&k_{n1}&\cdots&k_{nm}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{eqnarray}

which is an $(l+n)\times (l+m)$ matrix. Thus, such a $T$ exists and has the above form.

---

As far as I understand, we're dealing with something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why are the $d_i$'s not used here?

Comment: Explain!!! Why has someone chevroned this down?

Comment: $T$ maps whole $V$ *onto* $W'$. This $W'$ could then be embedded into *any* $W$ which has bigger dimension. So the rest part of $W$ (including the extended basis $d_1,..,d_p$) is *irrelevant* for $T$. $\quad$ *Any* linear map satisfies the criterium. Linear maps (after having bases fixed on both sides) straightly correspond to (multiplying from left by) *matrices*. $\quad$ For a clearer solution, forget $c_1,..c_n$ and show that $Tb_1,..,Tb_n$ is a basis in $W'$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dim V'+\dim W'=\dim V\implies\dim V'(=p,\text{say}),\dim W'(=q,\text{say})\le\dim V(=n,\text{say})$

Let $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_p\}$ be a basis of $V'.$ Extend this to a basis $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_p,b_1,...b_q\}$ of $V.$

Consider a basis $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_q\}$ of $W'.$

Define $T':B\to W$ by $T(v_i)=0~\forall~i=1(1)p$ and $T(b_i)=w_i~\forall~i=1(1)q.$

$T'$ has a unique extension to a linear transformation $T:V\to W.$

Verify that $\ker T=V'$ and $\text{range }T=W'.$